# Do I have to spend XP on rituals I earn by increasing my thaumaturgy?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, minds-eye-theatre

I am having a dispute with the assistant storyteller of our live action Vampire game.  Laws of the Night says I earn rituals when I increase the primary path of Thaumaturgy.  From the book:

> A character learns one Basic ritual automatically after learning Thaumaturgy.  As the vampire's primary path improves, additional rituals are learned, one appropriate to each level gained.  Thus, with Advanced Thaumaturgy, the vampire knows at least two Basic rituals, two Intermediate rituals, and one Advanced ritual.

The AST is saying I have to spend XP on those rituals based on the XP costs listed on page 124 for new rituals, but my reading of the paragraph I quoted is that paying for the Thaumaturgy earns me a ritual, because it says I *have* the rituals rather than saying I have an opportunity to buy them.

So who is right?

Comment: Hi MntlWard, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Comment: you probably need to go over your AST's head and talk directly to the DST (am I getting my hierarchy correct?  it's been a minute).

Comment: @DForck42 I think AST is OWbN and DST is MES/CAM.

Comment: @Jadasc if I'm remembering correctly, at MES/CAM, AST's (Assistant Story Tellers) report to the DST (District ST), who report to the RST (Regional), who report to the NST (National), who report to the board.

Comment: @DForck42 You're misremembering. In MES/CAM, it's VSTs (Venue) who report to DSTs (Domain), and then Regional and National above that. AVST is a position below VST, but they're in an assistive role and would be unlikely to be making calls like these.

Comment: @Jadasc ahh yes, you are correct.  I was only in MES for about a year

Comment: This game isn't connected to any regional stuff, as far as I know.  It's just my friend's game.  He said what I quoted sounds like what I think it says, but he didn't want to make a hard call on it.  Anyway, thanks for the help.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. You are already quoting the relevant section. Deviation from that (as the AST is appearing to do) might be a houserule for that specific group. Is it possible the AST is confusing rituals with paths?

Comment: I agree- the AST's version would have you paying twice for those rituals gained with Thaumaturgy- in that case, you'd be better off paying for the rituals on their own. It also dilutes the value of Thaumaturgy to make you pay extra/separately for the features it provides.

Comment: He's not getting them confused.  He's just looking at the page that describes the XP cost of "new rituals," and he's assuming that cost applies to these first earned rituals.